# jQuery 1.9.1 unrecognised expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having a strange error between two versions of some software I'm working on and I wondered what might cause this behaviour difference in jQuery 1.9.1

I have a line that works fine in my stable release:

```
this.$el.find('input:[name=file].js-file-input-box').focus().click();
```

However I'm doing some changes to it and in the new version jQuery (still 1.9.1) throws an 'unrecognized expression' error.
Now I know it's down to the colon so if I change it to

```
this.$el.find('input[name=file].js-file-input-box').focus().click();
```

It works.

What might cause this to work / not work - I don't know which version is wrong!?

Comment: did you check the missing colon after input?

Comment: `:` is used in the selector to recognize a expression filter, so your first selector is clearly wrong. now the question which was the old version that was not giving the error

Comment: my bad. The version with the colon works in jQuery 1.7.1. I need to get my eyes tested.

Comment: They are both wrong: pseudo selectors must be preceded by a colon. http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ I agree its works also without but I doubt if its supported.

Comment: @Andries Its a valid CSS selector.